# Can we integrate Google's IMA3 SDK on tvos9

Tags: tvos, google-ima, tvos9.1

I am integrating Google's IMA3 SDk on TVOS9. as per sample app, I have integrated the as per the sample code https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-ios/releases.

but I am getting following error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification imaMessage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f823a8886d0'
```

and the stack

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce2aff5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c22cdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce3361d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd80a9a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd80648 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   App                           0x000000010af420f1 -[IMAJavascriptBridge handleMessageInitialized:] + 157
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdf782c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdf756b _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdf72d2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce3cb02 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1986
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccf2409 _CFXNotificationPost + 633
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010bdba259 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    12  App                           0x000000010af43c72 -[IMAJavascriptSession didReceiveMessage:] + 304
    13  App                           0x000000010af43008 -[IMAJavascriptDispatcher processNewMessage:] + 310
    14  App                           0x000000010af42bcb -[IMAJavascriptDispatcher processNewMessageWithChannelName:data:] + 144
    15  App                           0x000000010af42633 -[IMAJavascriptBridge webView:didReceiveMessage:] + 165
    16  App                           0x000000010af5a8f9 -[IMAWKWebView userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:] + 164
    17  WebKit                              0x000000010f311ced _ZN28ScriptMessageHandlerDelegate14didPostMessageERN6WebKit12WebPageProxyERNS0_13WebFrameProxyERKNS0_18SecurityOriginDataERN7WebCore21SerializedScriptValueE + 217
    18  WebKit                              0x000000010f2c2b73 _ZN6WebKit29WebUserContentControllerProxy14didPostMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionEyyRKNS_18SecurityOriginDataEyRKNS1_13DataReferenceE + 221
    19  WebKit                              0x000000010f2c4868 _ZN3IPC13handleMessageIN8Messages29WebUserContentControllerProxy14DidPostMessageEN6WebKit29WebUserContentControllerProxyEMS5_FvRNS_10ConnectionEyyRKNS4_18SecurityOriginDataEyRKNS_13DataReferenceEEEEvS7_RNS_14MessageDecoderEPT0_T1_ + 142
    20  WebKit                              0x000000010f1239e5 _ZN3IPC18MessageReceiverMap15dispatchMessageERNS_10ConnectionERNS_14MessageDecoderE + 113
    21  WebKit                              0x000000010f2a6210 _ZN6WebKit15WebProcessProxy17didReceiveMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_14MessageDecoderE + 24
    22  WebKit                              0x000000010f0e191a _ZN3IPC10Connection15dispatchMessageENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_14MessageDecoderENS1_14default_deleteIS3_EEEE + 102
    23  WebKit                              0x000000010f0e3be2 _ZN3IPC10Connection18dispatchOneMessageEv + 114
    24  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000010bab0ad5 _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEv + 437
    25  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000010bab11b2 _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEPv + 34
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd56bc1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd4caec __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd4bfa3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd4b9b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110bcdad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010db9c8fc UIApplicationMain + 171
    32  App                           0x000000010af35b2d main + 109
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001107a99e9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Google IMA depends on WebKit which does not exist on tvOS, so you cannot use this on tvOS yet. Google will need to release a build specifically for tvOS...